# Prove that the set C has content zero

Tags: calculus, analysis, measure-theory

I'm a little lost in here with content zero. It is a question of a test o mine and the professor said it was wrong (I said it had content zero because it was a graph of a function) and I don't know where do I begin correctly. It is the following statement:

> *Consider constants $a,b>0$. Does the set $$C=\left\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \middle|
>  \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}= 1\right\}$$ have content zero? Justify your answer!!!*

**Definition 1.** A rectangle is any set of the form $R = [a, b] × [c, d]$. Its *area* is $(b − a)(d − c)$. Note that rectangles are, by definition, closed (they include their boundary points.)

**Definition 2.** A bounded set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ has *zero content* if for any $\varepsilon > 0$ one can find a finite number of rectangles $R_1,\dotsc, R_m \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that

1. $S \subset R_1 \cup \dotsb \cup R_m$, and
2. $\mathrm{area}(R_1) + \dotsb + \mathrm{area}(R_m) < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Can you find a point in $C$ ?

Comment: An ellipse is not the graph of a function.  It is, however, the union of the graphs of two functions...

Comment: What is "content"? Hausdorff content? Minkowski content?

Comment: It is the condition for the existence of double integrals.

Comment: Can you define the term "content," please?  This can mean different things in different contexts...

Comment: I'll give an example. You try to evaluate the area of a circle, but when you do so, the boundaries are irrelevant because it has content zero, or area zero, so you can evaluate the area of the circle $x^2+y^2<=1$ and $x^2+y^2<1$ and it gives the same result.

Comment: How is this different from 'measure?'

Comment: The definition is based in breaking the curve in infinity small rectangles or circles and evaluate its areas, then sum of all small areas is the area of the curve. I think it is based in mean value theorem.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the definition of content zero?

Comment: @GustavoAlvesdeOliveira all of what you've said so far sounds like Lebesgue measure.

Comment: I edited with the definition.

Comment: I found the definition here: http://www.math.wisc.edu/~angenent/376.2005/zerocontent-problems.pdf. Note that the last problem is very similar to this one.

Comment: OK, so the difference between measure and content as defined here is that we only consider **finite** unions of rectangles in the definition of content (for measure we allow the unions to be countably infinite). Do you have any theorems about content, or do you want an argument directly from the definition?

Comment: Btw the content being talked here is called Jordan content and Riemann integration is the theory corresponding to this kind of measure.

Comment: It has to start from the definition. I did not find a theorem. If the union two content zero sets are zero, then it has also to be proved. (seriously, my teacher is a pain in the @ss hahah)

Comment: Then I suggest you first prove the theorem that if two sets are of content $0$ then their union is also of content $0$ and then use induction to show that result is valid of union of $n$ sets.

Comment: you can prove that your set has measure zero and its compact because measure zero and compactness implies content zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C$ is the union of the graphs of two functions $f,g$ on $[-a,a]$, with  $f=\{(x,y)\in C: y\geq 0\}$  and $g=\{(x,y)\in C:y\leq 0\}.$ Since $g(x)=-f(x)$ for all $x\in [-a,a],$ it suffices to show that the content of the graph of $f$ is $0.$

(i). For $a>r>0$ let $g_r$ be the part of the graph of $f$ restricted to the domain $[-a,-a+r]\cup [a-r,a].$ Now $g_r$ is covered by two rectangles: $[-a, -a+r]\times [0,f(-a+r)], $ and $[a-r,a]\times [0,f(a-r)]$.

So the content of $g_r$ is at most $D(r)=r(f(a-r)+f(-a+r)).$ Since $f$ is continuous at $\pm a$ with $f(\pm a)=0,$ the value $D(r)$ can be as small as desired, by taking sufficiently small  $r$.

We can conclude that the content of the graph of $f$ is $0$ if we can show that the content of $f$ resticted to $[-a+r,a-r]$ is $0, $ ....

.... which we do by putting $p=-a+r$ and $q=a-r$ in the following:

(ii).  Lemma. For $p<q$ and for differentiable $f:[p,q]\to \mathbb R$  such that  $\sup \{|f'(x)|:x\in [p,q]\}=K<\infty , $  the content of the graph of $f $ on $[p,q]$ is $0.$

Proof: For $n\in \mathbb N$ let $d_n=\frac {q-p}{n}$ and let $a_j=a+jd_n$ for $0\leq j\leq n.$ The graph of $f$ on the interval $[a_j,a_{j+1}]$ is covered by the rectangle  $[a_j,a_{j+1}]\times [f(a_j)-Kd_n,\;f(a_j)+Kd_n].$  This rectangle has area $2K(d_n)^2.$ There are $n$ such rectangles, so the content of the graph of $f$ on $[p,q]$ cannot exceed $$n\cdot 2K(d_n)^2 =2K(q-p)^2/n.$$ Since $n$ can be any natural number, the content of the graph of $f$ on $[p,q]$ is zero.

This is not as general as  the comments and answer of Paramanand Singh but suffices for the Q.

Remarks: I hope I got "the graph of..." in all the right places. To a set-theorist  a function $is$ its graph.... In the Lemma it would also suffice that $f$ is Lipschitz-continuous on $[p,q]$ with Lipschitz constant $K$.

Answer (score 4):

This is an extension of my comments. So assume that you have proved the theorem about union of sets of content $0$ (proof is easy).

Now consider the part of $C$ which lies in first quadrant. This can be covered by $n$ rectangles. The diagonal points of $i$-th such rectangle are $(x_i, f(x_i)), (x_{i+1},f(x_{i+1}))$ where $x_{i} =ia/n$ and $f(x) =b\sqrt{1-(x/a)^{2}}$ (note that $i$ takes values $0,1,2,\dots,n-1$). Prove that the total area of such rectangles is $b/n$ which can be made smaller than any given positive number by choosing a large $n$. You will find that the fact that $f$ is monotone in interval $[0,a]$ will come handy here. Thus you will show that the content of the part in first quadrant is $0$. Similarly parts in other quadrants are also of content $0$.

---

For those who are well versed, the above procedure is the way we prove that a monotone function is Riemann integrable.

Comment: Very good point at the end, about Riemann integration.

Answer (score 0):

The circumference of an ellipse is approximatelly $B=\pi[3(a+b)-\sqrt{(3a+b)(a+3b)}]$(Ramanujan)

We can say that the  circumference is $O(B)$

Now we can find rectangles with sides $1/k$ and   area $1/k^2$ which can cover $C$

We need $O(kB)$ of them thus the whole $Vol(C)=O(\frac{B}{k})$